# Remove a sequence of pipe separated numbers using regex

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match a sequence of four numbers that are separated by pipes in a string. The numbers may be negative, float, or double digits, for example:

`13|5|-1|3` or `5|5|0|3` or `13|4|1.5|1`

The string may also contain additional numbers and words; a full example looks like so:

`SOME STRING CONTENT 13|5|-1|3 MORE 1.6 CONTENT HERE`

How could I identify those numbers between and to the left/right of the pipes using regex?

I have tried `[\d\-.\|]` which matches all digits, decimals, pipes, and negative signs but also find it matches the additional number/decimal content in the string. Any help on just selecting that one section would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\|\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?){3}\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `-?` Match an optional `-`
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:\|\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?){3}` Repeat 3 times the same as previous part preceded by a pipe
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qu3wJp/1)

Comment: The speed in which you answered this question is impressive! Many thanks. Could you explain the difference between your current answer and previous `\b\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\|\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?){3}\b`?

Comment: @jclark754 I have added a breakdown of the separate parts.

Comment: You move too fast :), will accept when the time limit allows. Again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As well use

```
(?<!\S)-?\d*\.?\d+(?:\|-?\d*\.?\d+){3}(?!\S)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/e5OEBv/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){3}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```